# adding SSL to Nginx from docker-compose environment

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, nginx-ingress

Good morning, trying to solve this problem for three days still doesnt have a clue, searched almost first 30 pages of Google and still didnt get it working, so asking questions on stack overflow might be a good choice.

Reason been for using docker compose is its ease to use, anyone on the team can just use docker compose up to pull the lastest image, nearly maintenance free.

This is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
  wise-nginx:
    image: nginx:1.22
    container_name: wise-nginx
    depends_on:
      - wise-client
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '433:433'
    extra_hosts:
      - "atswise.top:127.0.0.1"
    volumes:
      - '${PWD}/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
```

So I have figured out how to use docker inspect to read the volume line in wise-nginx, and uploaded the SSL certificates files in the folder, and ssl_certificate runs fine, below is my conf.d for Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 433 ssl;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    server_name atswise.top www.atswise.top;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /etc/nginx/conf.d/access.log;
    error_log /etc/nginx/conf.d/error.log;
    
    location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://wise-client:4200;
    proxy_set_header Host localhost:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

and there are some other locations.

For now I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED from Chrome from accessing the website using https, and website is running fine from http.

I know I should post error log, however its keep showing as 0 bytes, werid.
Anyone care to give some pointers? Thanks.

Anychange to my docker-compose.yml and conf.d to make it work?
According some results, I may need to add http_module to Nginx, however its running on a docker container, not sure it's the issue?